# Get all values for a specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

As simple as the title states, i want to get all values for for elements that contain a specific `data-attribute`. Any solutions I've found have been directly related to querying the value of the attribute which is not what I want.

So for example - if I have multiple elements with the attribute `data-help-id` how do I retrieve all those attributes either as an array or an object?

Comment: Look into `$('[data-help-id="your value"')`

Comment: @Brian That's the kind of solution I found that won't work for me - I don't have a value to specify in that query, I want the values for that data-attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to transform your jQuery object containing elements with the attribute you want into an array of values:

```
var $elements = $('[data-help-id]')
    , values = $elements.map(function () {
          return $(this).data('help-id');
      }).get();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/68kcg/